# An array and list of list properties

Tags: swift

I have an array of the objects. Every single object has another list. How to get the whole list of properties from the list? So as you can see there is a StatioItem array. Each stationItem owns a list of sensorItem objects. I want to get a list of id properties. How to do it?

> 

```
[StationItem {
    id = 114;
    stationId = 114;
    cityName = Wrocław;
    addressStreet = ul. Bartnicza;
    sensors = List<SensorItem> <0x6000001bb840> (
        [0] SensorItem {
            id = 642;
            stationId = 642;
            param = ParamItem {
                paramName = dwutlenek azotu;
                paramFormula = NO2;
                paramCode = NO2;
                idParam = 6;
            };
        },
        [1] SensorItem {
            id = 644;
            stationId = 644;
            param = ParamItem {
                paramName = ozon;
                paramFormula = O3;
                paramCode = O3;
                idParam = 5;
            };
        }
    );
}, StationItem {
    id = 70;
    stationId = 70;
    cityName = Oława;
    addressStreet = ul. Żołnierzy AK 9;
    sensors = List<SensorItem> <0x6000001b7840> (
        [0] SensorItem {
            id = 397;
            stationId = 397;
            param = ParamItem {
                paramName = dwutlenek azotu;
                paramFormula = NO2;
                paramCode = NO2;
                idParam = 6;
            };
        },
        [1] SensorItem {
            id = 400;
            stationId = 400;
            param = ParamItem {
                paramName = pył zawieszony PM10;
                paramFormula = PM10;
                paramCode = PM10;
                idParam = 3;
            };
        },
        [2] SensorItem {
            id = 20214;
            stationId = 20214;
            param = ParamItem {
                paramName = ozon;
                paramFormula = O3;
                paramCode = O3;
                idParam = 5;
            };
        }
    );
}]
```

Comment: `let sensorsIds = array.map{ aStation in aStation.sensors.map{ $0.id } }.flatMap{ $0 }` or something like that should do the trick.

Comment: It works. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do we need to do:
Iterate the array, for each station found, iterate over its sensor array. For each sensor found, keep only its id.

```
let ids = stations.map{ aStation in aStation.sensors.map{ $0.id } }.flatMap{ $0 }
```

With Sample:

```
struct StationItem {
    let id: Int
    let sensors: [SensorItem]
}

struct SensorItem {
    let id: Int
}

let stations: [StationItem] = [StationItem(id: 114, sensors: [SensorItem(id: 642),
                                                              SensorItem(id: 644)]),
                               StationItem(id: 70, sensors: [SensorItem(id: 397),
                                                             SensorItem(id: 400),
                                                             SensorItem(id: 2014)])]
```